# Updating request destination name and address

Tags: uber-api

I'm trying to set a request destination `name` and `address`.

I'm using following request: 
PATCH /requests/{request_id} with `end_address` and `end_nickname`:

```
{
  "end_latitude": -29.951063378432128,
  "end_longitude": -90.07152712622717,
  "end_nickname": "Tristan Testing",
  "end_address": "Tristan Testing"
}
```

It returns: 204 No Content, so expecting no error.

Then, if I get latest destination details:

```
"destination": {
  "latitude": -29.9510633784,
  "eta": 8034,
  "longitude": -90.0715271262
}
```

Destination coordinates are updated fine, but nickname and address not set anywhere.

How can I solve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please supply more info about your request - like full payload of the request (what parameters you used)?

Comment: Hi Sasa, I updated the issue description with all request payload and results. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ends up the issue is only for sandbox, as in `name` and `address` for `pickup` and `destination` are not exposed on sandbox, accoding to Uber API documentation.